# What is the approprate iterator to use when working with binary files in Python?

Tags: python, binaryfiles, enumerate

I'm attempting to read a binary file I've generated in C# with a python application, the file itself is just a set of alternating time stamps and attribute values.

What I'm having troubles with conceptualising what iterator I should use to loop through the file. The below code works when reading in the first 16 bytes, so I tried to use readlines() as the iterator wrapped around it but it looks like readlines ignores the 8 bytes and crams everything into a tuple with two items (int=0, bytes = entire file)

```
     with open(self.file_path, "rb") as binary_file:
        for line in enumerate(binary_file.readlines(8)):
            # Read the first 16 bytes; first time|value pair
            # C doubles are 8 bytes
            time_data = binary_file.readline(8)
            attr_data = binary_file.readline(8)

            # read the bytes into a double (a C double here, python floats are C doubles hence the %.2f print statement
            # needed if you want to get any decimals to print)
            [time] = struct.unpack('d', time_data)
            attr = struct.unpack('d', attr_data)

            print("Time stamp value: %.2f" % time)
            print("Attribute value: %f" % attr)
```

What method should I use to create an iterator that I can then check the index for odd/even numbers to be able to tell the difference between the two doubles?

Comment: `.readline()` is an *utterly meaningless* thing to do on a binary file; a newline character might arbitrarily be found as any of the bytes in your float values, without having anything to do with the structure of your data.  (Note that even if it worked, you'd be throwing away the data returned by the iterator, since you're redundantly reading data inside the loop.)  You just want to call `.read()` in a loop until it returns an empty (falsy) value; either `.read(8)` twice in each iteration like you're currently doing, or a single `.read(16)` which you'd then unpack using format `'dd'`.

Comment: Look here https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/19q8nt/psa_consider_using_numpy_if_you_need_to_parse_a/